# How to use vaadin-text-field in script module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, vaadin, web-component

I have tried to use [`vaadin-text-field`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-text-field) in a script module, but it fails with the following message

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/color.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Now I know that "Bare" import specifiers aren't supported in ES6 
But is there a way to make this work without hacking on the component's imports.
I mean locally of course

Here is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Polyfills only needed for Firefox and Edge. -->
  <script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="module">
    import {PolymerElement, html} from './node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
    import './node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-text-field/theme/lumo/vaadin-text-field.js';

    class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

      static get properties() { return { }}

      static get template() {
        return html`
          <vaadin-text-field></vaadin-text-field>
        `;
      }
    }

    customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
  </script>

  <my-element></my-element>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** I am using [server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to serve the file not polymer CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that serving the file with `polymer serve` is the fastest way to solve the problem.

According to [Polymer's Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/es6)

> The browser accepts only one kind of module specifier in an import
>   statement: a URL, which must be either fully-qualified, or a path
>   starting with /, ./ or ../. This works fine for importing
>   application-specific elements and modules:
>
> However, it's challenging when you're writing a reusable component,
>   and you want to import a peer dependency installed using npm. The path
>   may vary depending on how the components are installed. So Polymer
>   supports the use of Node-style named import specifiers
>
> Where @polymer/polymer is the name of the npm package. (This style of
>   specifier is sometimes called a "bare module specifier".)
>
> These module specifiers need to be transformed to paths before they're
>   served to the browser. The Polymer CLI can transform them at build
>   time, and the Polymer development server can transform them at
>   runtime, so you can test code without a build step. Many third-party
>   build tools, like WebPack and Rollup also support named modules.